# Trouble with Paths?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have a problem where I am creating an Android app using Firemonkey in Delphi XE6. The app consists of a TWebBrowser and a button...nothing fancy.
I am TRYING to display an xhtml file that is located on my SD card.
I "think" I am doing all the right things like using `"TPath.GetHomePath"` and putting my file in this location. - and made sure the permissions are set in the project.

Being a seasoned developer, I know that I need to use "file://" so the browser knows it a local file, as I have done a million times in Delphi over the years, and even checking the help file which uses the example `"WebBrowser1.Navigate('file://MyFile.pdf')"`

So I construct my URL by doing :

```
AppPath := TPath.Combine(TPath.GetHomePath, 'myfile.xhtml');
```

I then go:

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate('file://'+AppPath);
```

When the navigation happens, it tells me the file doesn't exist, `file:///data/data/com.embarcadero.WebBrowser/files/myfile.xhtml`
I spotted the 3 /'s i.e. file:/// and thought I would just hard coded the path into a string and got the same problem saying the file doesn't exists and it reverting back to file:///

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? its got me puzzled thats for sure! :-)

Thanks, Jeremy

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

> TPath.GetHomePath

i used

> TPath.GetPublicPath

which leads me to `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<myapp>/files/` folder (the one i need).

> TPath.GetHomePath

gives me `data/data/<myapp>/files/` which is not exists (i guess, maybe i need something like GetAbsolutePath).